# How to log what's being typed on the select2 input field and eventually updating another input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I'm having trouble logging in real time what's being typed on the select2 input field

My goal is to update another input field while the user in typing on the select2 search box

I tried many things but it's not working:
nothing is appearing in my console

```
$('.mySelect2').on("change",function(e){
  console.log("mySelect2 text", e.target.value)
  console.log("mySelect2 text $(this).val()", $(this).val())

  // #location is my other field that I want to update 
  $("#location").text(e.target.value);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events#listening-for-events), you need to use different event:

```
$('#mySelect2').on('select2:select', function (e) {
    var data = e.params.data;
    console.log(data);
});
```

---

Update: the following method allows to capture everything that the user types into the select2 input

```js
// In your Javascript (external .js resource or <script> tag)
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $select2 = $('.js-example-basic-single')
    $select2.select2();
    $('body').on('input', '.select2-search__field',  function() { 
          console.log(this.value);
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.4/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.4/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select class="js-example-basic-single" name="state">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    ...
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I already tried this, but nothing appears in the log. My goal is to log something at every keypress, not when the user selects something

Comment: I see, I misunderstood your question and I updated my answer with a straightforward way to capture all the input. Not sure, but maybe some of the "internal" select2 events can also be used for that (see https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events#internal-select2-events).

Comment: excellent, your answer combined with another answer on Github helped me find a solution to a problem that was bugging me.